# bootstrap image hover overlay with icon

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, hover

Trying to create similar effect on the image with CSS on bootstrap platform. Having some hard time to implement. What I'm trying to do is on image hover apply an transparent overplay with a box and a centered glyp-eye icon and it suppose to be responsive. Below is my code and the screenshot of the effect:

[image]

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

.pdf-thumb-box 
{
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: relative !important;
}

.pdf-thumb-title-active 
{
  color: #000;
}
.pdf-thumb-box-overlay 
{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.31);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pdf-thumb-box-overlay i 
{
  bottom: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="pdf-thumb-box">
      <a href="#2013-Katalog">
        <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay">
          <div class="center-box"></div><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> 
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Cn1ev16.jpg" alt="2013 Genel Katalog">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alternative solution I made with only using CSS.
http://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/ez470dxo/4/

```css
.pdf-thumb-box {
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: relative !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pdf-thumb-box-overlay {
  display: none;
}
.pdf-thumb-box a:hover .pdf-thumb-box-overlay {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, padding 0.8s linear;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.58);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.pdf-thumb-box-overlay span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="pdf-thumb-box">
      <a href="#2013-Katalog">
        <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x pdf-thumb-square"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-stack-1x pdf-thumb-eye"></i>
</span>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Cn1ev16.jpg" alt="2013 Genel Katalog">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="vertical-social-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="pdf-thumb-box">
      <a href="#2013-Katalog">
        <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x pdf-thumb-square"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-stack-1x pdf-thumb-eye"></i>
</span>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Cn1ev16.jpg" alt="2013 Genel Katalog">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="vertical-social-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="pdf-thumb-box">
      <a href="#2013-Katalog">
        <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x pdf-thumb-square"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-stack-1x pdf-thumb-eye"></i>
</span>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Cn1ev16.jpg" alt="2013 Genel Katalog">
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <style>
        body {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        .pdf-thumb-box {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: block;
        }

        .pdf-thumb-box-overlay {
            background: #000;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }
        .glyphicon-eye-open{
            margin-top:60px;
            color:red;
        }

        img {
            width: 362px;
        }

        </style>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pdf-thumb-box">
               <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay">
                <a href="#2013-Katalog">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
                </a>
             </div> 
                <img  class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Cn1ev16.jpg" alt="2013 Genel Katalog">

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>


   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>   
        <script>
        $(document)ready(function(){
            $(".pdf-thumb-box").hover(function() {

            var imgWidth = $(this).children("img").width();
            var imgHeight = $(this).children("img").height();
            var negImgWidth = imgWidth - imgWidth - imgWidth;

            $(this).children(".pdf-thumb-box-overlay").fadeTo(0, 0.8);

            $(this).css("width", (imgWidth)+"px");
            $(this).css("height", (imgHeight)+"px");


            $(this).children(".pdf-thumb-box-overlay").css("left", negImgWidth+"px");
            $(this).children(".pdf-thumb-box-overlay").css("visibility", "visible");

            $(this).children(".pdf-thumb-box-overlay").animate({"left": 0}, 250);

        }, function() {

            var imgWidth = $(this).children("img").width();
            var imgHeight = $(this).children("img").height();
            var negImgWidth = imgWidth - imgWidth - imgWidth;

            $(this).children(".pdf-thumb-box-overlay").animate({"left": negImgWidth}, 250);

        });
        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply here is the jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/dhs4bfgj/

Comment: There suppose to be regular image and once you hover on image the overlay and icon needs to appear.

Comment: Can you see the changes there?

Comment: I think you need to click update and share the new link

Comment: Thanks, I was working on the code too and make it worked but yours seems better win the transition effect.
here is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/ez470dxo/

Comment: But I have noticed you have made it using javascript, I think I would like to keep it simple with only using CSS. Thank you very much for the effort though, it is nice to see it could have been accomplished easier with JS.

Comment: Worked hard but that's fine. :/

Comment: Do you think can I add some kind of CSS transition effect like yours  to my code without using JS , it does not have to be exact same,? http://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/ez470dxo/ The transition code I have added did not worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64560/discussion-between-tan-kucukhas-and-vcrzy).

Comment: Just came across this as I was looking for a similar solution and this does not work properly.  `display:inline-block !important;` on the outer box causes sizing problems with the col-md-4 divs.  Alignment is off and the images are not contained within the col-md-4's as they should be causing the whole row to be misaligned.  It's fine on small screens but on md and up where are all three are in the same row it is not spaced/sized correctly.